# Using a file path as primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have table which will only contain information about files, so, as the file path is unique and can identify any entry, i thought i should use it as primary key.

Although, i'm having a few problems like needing to specify a key length (error 1170). What should i do? Use an integer as primary key and every time i need to access information on file 'x', do a "where FilePath=x"?

Thanks for the time dispensed reading my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most databases, it's inefficient (or even impossible) to create an index for a string column that is long enough to store a deep file path.  This is good situation to use a surrogate key.

Another option would be to compute a fixed-length hash from the file path using an inexpensive hash function such as `MD5()` (though MD5 is not strong enough to use for passwords, it's strong enough to ensure uniqueness given the input data in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Use an int as a primary key and put Unique in the field for the file path.

```
CREATE TABLE `cms`.`test` (
    `id` INT( 32 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `filepath` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
UNIQUE (
    `filepath`
)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

Comment: It shouts the same error (1170) as if it were the primary key. But thanks for the try :)

Comment: Sorry, actually your code works. It was me who was trying to use TEXT instead of VARCHAR(255). But i think VARCHAR(255) is too short for file paths, don't you?

Comment: Go here, http://lipsum.com/ and put 255 bytes into the field, the text shown is that length.

Comment: Well, NTFS has a maximum of 32,767 unicode characters and linux limits it usually to 4096 bytes (and filesystems like ext2/3 don't define any limit at all). This might be a bit theoretical, but 255 characters is very likely to be too short in these days.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify a maxlength for a filepath and change the column to a varchar?

[This article explains the error](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/09/mysql-error-1170-42000-blobtext-column-used-in-key-specification-without-a-key-length/).  Basically, you can't put a key on a text or blob column because a key needs a length of which to check uniqueness against.  But text and blob columns don't support lengths.  So you can't use they in a key.

Varchar columns can go up to 65K characters in later versions of MySQL

> Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Comment: That would do the trick but in my mind, 255 characters is too short file file paths. I would like to be capable of long file names. Is there a way?

Comment: Now that i tried using varchar(65535) it says that the key length is limited to 1000 and i'm using version 5.1.31.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a natural key (file path/name) use a surrogate key (int)

I would make the primary key an INT, and put any path & file into in a different column.  It would be slow to have a long string as a key, and/or as a foreign key in other tables.

You might want to split the file name from the path, and/or only store part of the path.  The main root of the path could be a config setting that you append onto the database partial path+file name.

When we store file info, we just store the name, the path is build out based on other data: related item (order, incident, job, etc) and then the ID of that other data, etc...